# run external javascript within php file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to run a function within a external JavaScript code but it doesn't seem to work/launch, I know for sure that exists is greater than 0 but i'm not sure if my implementation of javascript is even correct.

Here's part of the code that's relevant

```
    $exists = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gu_customer WHERE email='$email'"));
echo $exists;


if ($exists > 0) {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='validation.js'>\n";
    echo "emailTaken();";
    echo "</script>";

}
```

Comment: is the script part showing on the rendered page? You can check that with developers tools on your browser..

Comment: the only thing that shows up on the page is 1 from echo $exist, other than that it's empty

Comment: You have both script SRC and inline javascript. The inline gets ingnored. Choose one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with PHP.

A script element can load the script from a URL (via the `src` attribute) **or** the text node inside the script.

One script element = One script.

You are trying to two scripts with one script element.

The browser is running the script from the URL, but isn't calling the `emailTaken` function that is (presumably) inside it.

```
echo "<script src='validation.js'></script>\n";
echo "<script>\n";
echo "emailTaken();";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: I see what you mean with the src attribute however my function is within validation.js, wouldn't I still have it in-between the script tags? if so it still doesn't seem to work that way

Comment: No. A JavaScript file should contain JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: Sorry I think I'm not clear enough, I just want to clarify a few things as I'm trying to learn as your answer worked. Why do you open and close the script twice; I assumed you open the script tag with src and close it when you have called your functions.

Comment: @Wolf the first script is devoted to `validation.js` and references the external script. It can only refer to that one script, it cannot have a second script inside of its tags. You need the second script in order to run `emailTaken()`. The second script tags are for the second script, while the first script tags are for the external script. They cannot be combined.

Comment: I've added the validation.js file to head of my html and tried to call a simple alert function but it doesn't seem to work, network tab in developer mode shows that js is being downloaded but the function wont work. Writing the function on the html does seem to work though, what could be the problem?

Comment: There are lots of things that could be wrong (including the problem shown in the question). You'd need to show some code to tell what is wrong though (and looking at the JavaScript console in the developer tools would probably be sensible to)